# canActivate guard works only after refresh

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing, canactivate

I have canActivate guard which is on all routes (on the parent route). It works correctly when I go to any link first time, but then, when I'm changing routes it does not work. 
Guard is about logged in users (If api returns that I am logged in I return true, else I redirect it to Sign in page)
What I should do?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the same guard that you have defined, implement the CanActivateChild interface, and call the same logic. In your routes, define both the CanActivate, and the CanActivateChild.

In your guard

```
@Injectable()
export class MyGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {

  constructor() {}

  canActivate() {
    // Your logic here to identify the value to return
  }

  canActivateChild() {
     return this.canActivate();
  }
}
```

In your routing

```
let routes:Routes = [
 { 
   path: 'myPath', 
   canActivate: [ MyGuard ] 
   canActivateChild: [ MyGuard ],
   children: [
     { path: 'mychild1', .... },
     { path: 'mychild2', .... }
   ]
]
```

Read this guide on angular.io re protecting child routes : https://angular.io/guide/router#canactivatechild-guarding-child-routes